# Hyperplane containing union of two intersecting lines in $\mathbb P^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $l_1, l_2$ be two lines in $\mathbb P^3$(over $\mathbb C$) such that they intersect. Then is it always possible to obtain a hyperplane containing both of them?

Does anything like hyperplane generated by $l_1 \cup l_2$ and a point outside it make any sense in this case? ( Does the fact which says that a plane contains a 2 dimensional family of lines on it contributes anything in this case?)

Can someone give me a concrete example?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: If you translate the question to linear algebra it becomes elementary.

Comment: @Sasha, If we write $l_1 =Z(f_1) \cap Z(f_2)$ and $l_2 = Z(g_1) \cap Z(g_2)$ such that all $4$ hyperplanes are independent, then might be they don't intersect and hence one of them has to be linear combitation of others and hence we get a hyperplane which is $1$ of four of them. Does this make sense?